# Python - Getting page ID from JSON

Tags: python, json

```
{"query":{"normalized":[{"from":"hijab","to":"Hijab"}],"pages":{"68301":{
```

In Linux (Python):

```
>>> data['query']['pages']
{u'68301': {u'extract': u'<p/>"</b>Hijab</b>" or "</b>\u1e25ij\u0101b</b>" (/h\u026a\u02c8d\u0292\u0251\u02d0b/, /h\u026a\u02c8d\u0292\xe6b/, /\u02c8h\u026a.d\u0292\xe6b/ or /h\u025b\u02c8d\u0292\u0251\u02d0b/;Arabic: \u062d\u062c\u0627\u0628\u200e, <small>pronounced&#160;</small>[\u0127i\u02c8d\u0292\xe6\u02d0b] ~ [\u0127i\u02c8\u0261\xe6\u02d0b]) is a veil which covers the head which is particularly worn by Muslim women beyond the age of puberty in the presence of non-related adult males.</p>', u'ns': 0, u'pageid': 68301, u'title': u'Hijab'}}
```

Can anyone help me how to fetch that number (**68301**)

Comment: is `data['query']['pages']` a `dict` or `str`?

Comment: @tcaswell: That's definitely a `dict`; no quotes around the representation in the python interpreter there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that is a detail I had never noticed before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is a key in the dictionary:

```
>>> data['query']['pages'].keys()
[u'68301']
```

`.keys()` returns a list of dictionary keys, see the [Python `dict` type documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for the full API of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Sine this is a dictionnary, you can use the `keys`function :

```
data['query']['pages'].keys()
```